# Showing rating other than specified Step Size on Android Rating Bar

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

So, I have a basic RatingBar. I want to let the user only rate the page on increments of 1 star, so I did:

```
ratingBar.setStepSize(1);
```

and it works.

Now I want to take the average rating and set it to the average of all of the ratings (which may be a non-integer number). If I set the rating like this:

```
ratingBar.setRating(2.5f);
```

it rounds it up and displays 3 stars. and `Log.d("Rating", Float.toString(ratingBar.getRating()));` returns 3.0

If I set `ratingBar.setStepSize(.5);" it works, but I want users to be only able to SET the rating in increments of 1 but be able to DISPLAY increments of .1. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display a separate dialog in onClick of rating-bar, that contains another rating-bar with stepSize=0.5 .

Or you can set the stepSize of your rating-bar to 0.5 then in onClick event set it to 1 .